# Chebyshev polynomials on a union of two intervals -- or -- can you read German?

Tags: polynomials, optimization

I would like to know the answer to the following question. Let $X = [-1,-\alpha] \cup [\alpha,1]$ and let $P_n$ be the set of monic polynomials of degree $n$. How close to zero is the polynomial in $P_n$ that deviates least from zero? 
More formally, let us define $$E_n = \min_{p \in P_n} \max_{x \in X} |p(x)|$$ I am asking for what $E_n$ is, or, failing that, an upper bound that reveals how fast $E_n$ decays with $n$.

If $\alpha=0$, then the optimal $p_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of degree $n$ and in that case $E_n = 1/2^{n-1}$.

Now for the second part of the title. Some references suggest that the problem has actually been solved in the sequence of papers

N. Achyeser, “Über einige Funktionen, welche in zwei gegebenen Interwallen am wenigsten von Null abweichen. I Teil”, Bulletin de l'Académie des Sciences de l'URSS. Classe des sciences mathématiques et na, 1932, no. 9, 1163–1202

N. Achyeser, “Über einige Funktionen, welche in zwei gegebenen Intervallen am wenigsten von Null abweichen. II Teil”, Известия Академии наук СССР. VII серия. Отделение математических и естественных наук, 1933, no. 3, 309–344

N. Achyeser, “Übеr einige Funktionen, welche in zwei gegebenen Intervallen am wenigsten von Null abweichen. III Teil”, Известия Академии наук СССР. VII серия. Отделение математических и естественных наук, 1933, no. 4, 499–536.

The papers are in German and are available [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=5154&option_lang=eng) and [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=5007&option_lang=rus) and (I do not have the reputation to post the third link, but googling the title leads to it). However, I cannot read German and cannot read off the answer from the papers. Could someone who can read it quickly glance at these papers and say if they do indeed contain an expression or a bound for $E_n$, and if so, what it is?

Comment: I have skimmed the links and it does seem that the papers treat this kind of problem for several settings. However, it's quite long and I couldn't find an abstract/conclusion section which just states the result you were looking for without reading too much of it.